Setting AVX512 vector to zero/non-zero sometimes causes signal SIGILL on Godbolt
On Godbolt, this executes fine:
volatile __m512i v = _mm512_set_epi64(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    

but all zeros does not:
 volatile __m512i v = _mm512_set_epi64(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

It produces signal SIGILL. Illegal instruction?
Why is this?
I'm using clang 18.1 with flags -std=c++23 -O0 -mavx512vl.
In fact, if I change optimization level, the effect seems to invert. So i'd just like to know why setting different inputs can caused these issues?

@PeterCordes Ahhhh, I assumed Godbolt handled that. Makes sense!

@PeterCordes Please do feel free to put as an answer.

Was checking for an existing duplicate before doing so; I know I've said this before but maybe only in comments or as part of other answers.

You got an AWS instance that doesn't support AVX-512.
You sometimes get Zen 3 (-march=znver3).
It varies from run to run and I don't know of any way to request a specific instance type.  You can use -march=native and #ifdef __AVX512F__ so your test gets omitted if not supported.
The instance types I remember seeing in the past are Cascade Lake, Ice Lake, and Zen 3.  There might now be newer Intel and maybe newer AMD in the mix.

Neither of those vector constants needs a 512-bit instruction to materialize in a register (but might anyway with optimization disabled).  But both will use a single 512-bit store to init the volatile so both versions should make asm that uses an AVX-512 instruction.  As you can see from the asm on Godbolt using a ZMM register.

This definitely explains it because the outcome kept changing each time I compiled. It's a shame we can't guide Godbolt to intel vs AMD Instance.
